# apn_sender gem daemon not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rake, apple-push-notifications, daemon

Im using apn_sender for rails 3 and i have been able to install the gem and get it working just fine by using

```
rake apn:sender
```

I have tried to get it started in production mode on a ubuntu box by starting the daemon and it does not seem to work. When i type

```
script/apn_sender --environment=production --verbose start
```

I dont see anything. No log present.

when i try to type

```
script/apn_sender status
```

It returns with

```
apn_sender: no instances running
```

Just trying to understand why it is not running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just solved this problem. Try to create a file called 'script' in generators/apn_sender/templates . . 
**Put this in your script file**

```
# !/usr/bin/env ruby

# Daemons sets pwd to /, so we have to explicitly set RAILS_ROOT
RAILS_ROOT = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..'))

require 'rubygems'
require 'apn'
require 'apn/sender_daemon'

APN::SenderDaemon.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

bash 'rails g apn_sender' in your terminal and will create 'script/apn_server' with same content as above

After that bash this code

```
./script/apn_server --environment=production --verbose start
```

it will create log/apn_sender.log . Try running

`APN.notify('token',{:alert => '#' , :badge => 1})`

or else in rails c to confirm if it works or not , and of course 
`rake apn:sender`

Hope it will help :)

**EDIT**
You have to install redis and configure